# Cubase & EZDrummer Pair for Linux

Tags: linux, audio, music-production

I am an amateur musician and often record my compositions. I use Cubase 5 and EZDrummer while recording.

However, I now move to Ubuntu 14.04 from Windows 7. Therefore, I need a sofware which provides:

- Multichannel recording
- Drag&Drop and WYSIWYG interface

in addition, a drum machine like EZDrummer.

I've heard Ardour and Hydrogen but I'm not sure if I'd be comfortable with them after using Cubase 5.

Could someone, who used Cubase 5 and EZDrummer help me? Should I move to Ubuntu 14.04 or stay where I am?